# Infinite $digest Loop while using date-picker within ng-repeat object

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using ui-bootstrap date-picker within ng-repeat in angularjs. But while selecting on any date, I am getting Infinite $digest Loop error in console. I have a data structure like following.

```
$scope.colorConfigData = [
  {
    "columns": [
      {
        "label": "Employee Id",
        "type": "int8",
        "componentType": "Text field",
        "filters": [
          {
            "id": "=",
            "text": "equal to"
          },
          {
            "id": "!=",
            "text": "not equal to"
          },
          {
            "id": "<",
            "text": "less than"
          },
          {
            "id": ">",
            "text": "greater than"
          },
          {
            "id": "<=",
            "text": "less than equal to"
          },
          {
            "id": ">=",
            "text": "greater than equal to"
          },
          {
            "id": "between",
            "text": "in between"
          },
          {
            "id": "is not null",
            "text": "has any value"
          },
          {
            "id": "is null",
            "text": "has no value"
          }
        ],
        "operator": "=",
        "filterValue": "5"
      },
      {
        "label": "Date Of Birth",
        "type": "timestamp",
        "componentType": "Date",
        "filters": [
          {
            "id": "=",
            "text": "equal to"
          },
          {
            "id": "!=",
            "text": "not equal to"
          },
          {
            "id": "<",
            "text": "less than"
          },
          {
            "id": ">",
            "text": "greater than"
          },
          {
            "id": "between",
            "text": "in between"
          },
          {
            "id": "is not null",
            "text": "has any value"
          },
          {
            "id": "is null",
            "text": "has no value"
          }
        ],
        "operator": "=",
        "first_dt_inp_opnd": false,
        "filterValue": "2015-07-27T18:30:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "colorColumns": [
      {
        "label": "Employee Id",
        "type": "int8",
        "componentType": "Text field"
      },
      {
        "label": "Date Of Birth",
        "type": "timestamp",
        "componentType": "Date"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To explain the above structure, I have combinations of color filters. The outer array represent a combination while combination.columns will be columns chosen for filtering purpose.
So, my html ng-repeat structure is like follows

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="colorCombination in colorConfigData" ng-form="colorCombinationForm">

<select class="form-control" ng-change="updateColorColumnFilter(colorCombination.currentColumn, $index)" ng-model="colorCombination.currentColumn" ng-options="colorColumn as colorColumn.label for colorColumn in colorCombination.colorColumns" name="colorColumn" data-placeholder="{{entity + 'Select Column'| translate}}">
<option value="">Select Column</option></select>

<div ng-repeat="colorConfig in colorCombination.columns" ng-form="colorForm">
<!-- choose operator-->
<!-- if colorConfig.operator === int8, then text box -->
<!-- if colorConfig.operator === timestamp, then datepicker below -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{format}}" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" name="filterValFirst" required ng-model="colorConfig.filterValue" is-open="colorConfig.first_dt_inp_opnd"/>
<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'first_dt_inp_opnd', colorConfig)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button></span>
</div>
</div>
```

For other fields like int8(text field), its working fine. but when I select date-picker variable, then I get the infinite digest error. I am wondering what might trigger the situation.

** updateColorColumnFilter(), pushes a column into colorConfigData[index].columns.

```
//Open function
$scope.open = function($event, opened, element) {
                $event.preventDefault();
                $event.stopPropagation();
                element[opened] = true;
            };
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please paste your controller having open function

Comment: Edited with open function.

Answer (score 0):

My bad !! Nothing was wrong with either datepicker or ng-repeat. I somehow ended up wrapping the date model to new Date() again. So describes the infinite $digest cycle.